# Is it possible to include interaction terms without main effects in the MuMIn::dredge function?

Tags: r, glm, mumin, model-comparison

I am doing some model comparison with a glmer fit with lme4. My global model has 4 fixed effects and 1 random effect, plus interactions between 3 of the fixed effects:

response ~ a + b * c * d + (1|e)

The dredge function returns models with both double and triple interactions, but the fixed effects are always included in the model when interactions involving that variable are included. I want to compare all model combinations with these variables, including models that have an interaction term without the main effect, for example:

response ~ a + b + b:c + (1|e)  or
response ~ a + c + b:c + a:b:c + (1|e)

Is this possible with the dredge() function? Or any other suggestions for ways to accomplish this? It is a LOT of models to specify by hand.

Comment: Would you be willing to say a little bit more/give some context about *why* you want to do this? It doesn't usually make sense to fit models that violate the principle of marginality, except sometimes as an approach to hypothesis testing ... ?  I can think of some ways to hack this, but I'm not sure you should ...

Comment: hint: use `model.matrix()` to expand all of your interactions into separate variables, rename them to make them legal variable names, then use `reformulate()` to construct a long formula containing each of those columns separately ...

Comment: @ Ben Bolker Yes! I have specific hypotheses to test that include interactions but not the main effects. The study is a before-after control-impact design so I want to know, for example, if the response variable differed between control and impact before impact and the magnitude of the difference between control and impact changed after impact. The third interacting effect is a grouping variable for soil type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by warning that you should only violate the *principle of marginality* if you have good reason to do so/know what you're doing (there's a reason that `MuMIn` sets the defaults the way it does ...). With that said (*untested* because no reproducible example was given):

1. use `model.matrix()` to construct a matrix containing all of the separate variables you need for the fixed-effect component:

```r
X <- model.matrix(~ a + b*c*d, data = yourdata)
colnames(X) <- make.names(colnames(X)) ## convert to syntactically allowed names
```

(this will also expand factor variables into contrast/dummy variables; if you don't want this, you have to be a little more precise)

2. make a new data frame containing these variables (and your random effects grouping variables) and use `reformulate()` to combine all of those variables with the random effects:

```r
newdata <- data.frame(X, yourdata[c("e", "response")])
form <- reformulate(c(colnames(X), "(1|e)", response = "response")
```

3. Fit the model:

```r
model <- glmer(form, family = ..., data = newdata)
```

4. Dredge away!